# How to split logback logs based on "category"

Tags: logging, logback, mdc

I have a servlet that routes request to either a "live" or "test" system.

The servlet knows this based on the URI path. I would like to write the logs in two separate files 1 for live one for test.

So I know I need to use mdc

So...

```
class MyServlet ... {
    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("com.xxx.abc");

    HttpServletRequest(...)
    {
        if(path contains "live")
            MDC.put("production", "Live");
        else
            MDC.put("production", "Test");

        logger.info("Request processed...");
    }
}
```

In my logback.xml I have two appenders. How do I tell the logger to pick the right appender based on the MDC value of test or live?

Answer (score 0):

Answering an old question here but this looks like the perfect candidate for Logback's [SiftingAppender](http://logback.qos.ch/apidocs/ch/qos/logback/access/sift/SiftingAppender.html).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

    <appender name="SIFTER" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.sift.SiftingAppender">
        <discriminator>
            <key>production</key>
            <defaultValue>unknown</defaultValue>
        </discriminator>
        <sift>
            <appender name="FILE-${production}" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
                <file>${production}.log</file>
                <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
                    <pattern>...</pattern>
                </layout>
            </appender>
        </sift>
    </appender>

    <root level="ALL">
        <appender-ref ref="SIFTER" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

The value of `production` will be substituted into the log file name. So, log events which contain the MDC value `production=Live` will be written to `Live.log` via the `FILE-Live` appender and log events which contain the MDC value `production=Test` will be written to `Test.log` via the `FILE-Test` appender.